# How to tell if iOS user has disabled iCloud Calendar after initially having it enabled

Tags: ios, calendar, icloud

our problem:
iOS user launches our app and enabled calendar integration via iCloud (they have Settings > iCloud > Calendars checked on)
Our app populates a new iCloud calendar for them.

later, if the user disabled iCloud Calendar via Settings app, and returns to our app, our app has no way of knowing this was disabled. Any checks to find calendars still show the iCloud Calendar (even tho it was turned on in Settings)

Any tips or advice on working around this?

Answer (score 3):

after much searching, finally settled on a solution. it was not clearly answered but on other somewhat related questions finally found a way to detect if iCloud Calendar is off (even if iCloud was on)

the logic is, check and store a local calendar source, then check for iCloud calendars. If we detect iCloud, actually check and see if there are Calendars in iCloud (to detect if iCloud Cals are off) and if iCloud Cals are off use the local cal instead.

Works good until we bring up GMail and Google Calendars...another battle for another day. If anyone has input on that, greatly appreciated. Seems we gotta go thru the Google Cal API and hook in there.

```
EKSource *localCalSource;

self.calendarSource = nil;
for (EKSource *source in eventStore.sources) 
{
    if (self.calendarSource == nil && source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal) 
    {
        self.calendarSource = source;
        localCalSource = self.calendarSource;
        TLog([self isLocalLoggingOn], "Found local cal source!");
    }

    // if iCloud is enabled, grab that source and return it
    if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeCalDAV && [[source.title lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"icloud"])
    {

    if([source calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent].count>0)
    {     
    //Check to see if Calendar is enabled on iCloud
        self.calendarSource = source;     
    }else{      
    //Calendar is Disabled use LOCAL
            self.calendarSource = localCalSource;   
    }
        break;
        TLog([self isLocalLoggingOn], @"Found %@", source.title);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is one flaw in this approach (found so far) - if the user has iCloud Calendars on, and somehow manually deleted all the iCloud Calendars, this will consider iCloud Cals turned off.

Comment: did you find a good solution for the full problem with Gmail?

Comment: @ilan no, we didnt, we havent looked at this in a while, so hopefully it is better now.